# how can i make my program more responsive? (program that loads atleast 200 files) - i might have 1 idea

Tags: c#, database, file, filestream

first - i want to say sorry for my butchered English.

I am building a program that uses a lot of files. i have a lot of foreach loops that loops through the harddisk and those files (atleast 200 files - 600 bytes each file in average), the loop is using XPath to search for values in the file (the files are XML files of course)

I need to find a way to make my program more responsive - i thought of one which is the following:
Computers memory has a faster speed of loading than computer harddisk - and i thought - maybe i should load those files to the memory and than loop the memory instead of looping the harddisk.., by the way if someone can tell me how much faster computers memory are (from harddisks) than thanks

Thanks in advanced..
Din

if someone didn't understand my English i will try to explain again

Comment: Do you mean 'responsive' or 'faster'?

Comment: @Marcel My guess is the OP is viewing them one in the same due to language barriers...although I know that responsive may indicate work being done on the UI thread...and faster is the rate at analyzing the data...fair question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach I think of is [PLINQ in C#4.0](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2007/04/04/introducing-plinq.aspx). Group these XML files and query them with LINQ-to-XML parallelly. The following is a simple example, which loads all xml files in C:\xmlFolder and choose those documents which contains an element whose name is "key".

```
List<XDocument> xmls = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\XmlFolder").AsParallel()
                          .Select(path => XDocument.Load(path))
                          .Where(doc => doc.Descendants()
                                           .Any(ele => ele.Name.Equals("key")))
                          .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should parse the XML files in a different thread and create objects with the required information, this way you will have instant access to the information.

Comment: If you go this route make sure to dispose what you no longer need as holding all the data in memory is not needed and will cause problems if your file size increases...

Comment: 600 files * 1Kbyte = 600Kbytes so currently and in middle term no need to do that (IMHO).

Comment: It is best practice...holding on to something you don't need has no value and will not allow anything to scale...

Comment: Mmmm ... it is best practice to Dispose what is not needed but that's something related to common sense and not with this question.

Answer (score 0):

Define "responsive."  Do you mean that you want UI cues to continue to happen, or that you want to continue to be able to do other things in the UI while it's processing the files?

The former is easy, you can just toss in the occasional `Application.DoEvents()` in your loops.  This will prompt the UI to perform any cues that are waiting (such as draw the window, etc.).

The latter is going to involve multi-threading.  Diving into that is a bit more complex than can be taught in a paragraph or two, but some Google searches for "c# .net multi threading tutorial" should yield a ton of results.  If you're not familiar with the basic concept of what multi-threading provides, I can further explain it.

Comment: @Aaron: Good point.  I guess I assumed WinForms without being explicitly told either way.

Comment: when i mean "responsive" i mean that i have a text editor in my program and when the user enters something the program loops through the files, by looping those files the cursor "cues" for a sec and than shows up again (this is because the program is looping through files which makes the computer stuck for a sec - my cpu usage raises in 20% for a sec)

Comment: @dinbrca: Sounds like it's processing UI cues properly then, the thread is just occasionally waiting on the heavier processing steps.  You'll definitely want to offload those steps to separate threads then.

Comment: @David: so, you mean that i should use threads? can i have a good link to a good tutorial. also - shouldn't i also load the files to the memory and remove them when i don't need them anymore, this will make the processing much faster due to faster access to the files isn't it?

Comment: @dinbrca: You should _definitely_ release resources (such as files) as soon as they're no longer needed, always.  As for "loading into memory" this should essentially be happening already (unless you're loading the files in a way that's unfamiliar to me).  As for a good tutorial, there are _tons_ out there.  I personally don't know which ones are superior to others.  But it's probably safe to start with Microsoft's: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @David: I read a bit inside the link you gave me, still what do i make the producer and what do i make the consumer? is it: producer - loads a file, consumer - reads the file?, by the way - thanks for the help, also i forgot to mention i am using WPF to create my app

Comment: @David: also i forgot to ask, will the producer-consumer will make my program responsive for sure?

Answer (score 0):

Use a BackgroundWorker or a ThreadPool to spawn off multiple threads for the I/O, and have then read the data into a Queue (this is assuming the total size of your data is not too large).  Have another thread(s) reading off of that Queue, and doing your internal xPath logic to pull whatever you need from those files.

Essentially, think of it as an instance of the [Producer/Consumer design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem), wherein your I/O reader threads are producers, and your XPath logic threads are consumers.

The type of the object in the queue could be just a byte-array, but I'd suggest a custom C# class that contains the byte array, as well as some of the file metadata in case you need it for whatever reason.

Answer (score -5):

You can use database for storing XML files, it will be faster, more secure and reliable than you current schema. You can build indexes, concurrent access is enabled, XQuery/Xpath is supported and much more "pluses".

If you have only XML files, you can consider Native XML Databases, or if you have other types as well you can consider XML enabled DBMLS (such as Oracle or DB2).

Comment: -1 for suggesting use of DB w/o having a slightest idea what the program is doing, why etc, but knowing there is 120K of data.

Comment: He is talking about 200-600 files, and querying all of them. After tuning database correctly, all of the queries will much more faster than any of your "brilliant" non-db ideas. Waiting for you better and faster idea, if you have.

Comment: He doesn't have 200-600 files -- please read the question again.  I'm not going to optimize something I don't understand.  Using DB for everything is a really bad idea.

Comment: There's no point in using a database if this is a batch-type parsing, for example.